# HTML tags being removed after theme_preprocess_node

Tags: 8, theming

I am using theme_preprocess_node to modify an HTML tag, but the tag is being stripped somewhere in the theme layer.

mytemplate.twig

```
{% if node.field_embedded_media.value %}
  {{ content }}
```

mytheme.theme

```
    function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
      if ($variables['view_mode'] == 'ebook_export') {
        $contentBody = $variables['node']->get('body')->value;

        $pattern = '/<drupal-media/';
        $replace = '<drupal-media data-view-mode="markdown_link"';
        $contentBody = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $contentBody);

        $variables['content']['body'] = array(
            '#markup' => $contentBody
          );
        }
     }
```

Original input (node body value):

```
<drupal-media data-align="center" data-entity-type="media" data-entity-uuid="269d4491-9866-403c-90e3-c1298e9857de"></drupal-media>

This is some text.

<drupal-media data-align="center" data-entity-type="media" data-entity-uuid="269d4491-9866-403c-90e3-c1298e9857de"></drupal-media><pre>

This is some more text.
```

dpm($contentBody) in mytheme_preprocess_node (this is what I want to output, and it's correct here)

```
<drupal-media data-view-mode="markdown_link" data-align="center" data-entity-type="media" data-entity-uuid="269d4491-9866-403c-90e3-c1298e9857de"></drupal-media>

This is some text.

<drupal-media data-view-mode="markdown_link" data-align="center" data-entity-type="media" data-entity-uuid="269d4491-9866-403c-90e3-c1298e9857de"></drupal-media>

This is some more text.
```

Actual HTML output on page render (this is what I get, and the `<drupal-media>` tags are gone)

```
This is some text.

This is some more text.
```

The `<drupal-media>` tags got stripped.  How do I prevent them from being stripped?  I don't understand enough about the theme layer to determine where this is happening.

Comment: I think you need a more granular preprocess hook. I can't swear that this will work, but try `template_preprocess_field()` on your body field. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_field/8.6.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in Render API overview, the value passed in `#markup` is sanitized via [`\Drupal\Component\Utility\Xss::filterAdmin()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Utility%21Xss.php/function/Xss%3A%3AfilterAdmin/8.8.x). You can eventually pass the tags not to filter via the `#allowed_tags` properties, but the tag attributes could still be sanited.

To have full control on what it is sanitized, you should use `#theme` or `#type` instead of `#markup`. (The first is my choice when the markup is rendered only in a single place/page. Alternatively, you could also use [`#inline_template`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21InlineTemplate.php/class/InlineTemplate/8.8.x) as in the following example code taken from the documentation page.

```
$build['hello'] = [
  '#type' => 'inline_template',
  '#template' => "{% trans %} Hello {% endtrans %} <strong>{{name}}</strong>",
  '#context' => [
    'name' => $name,
  ],
];
```

It allows to use any Twig filter Drupal core can use and to have full control over the rendered tags.
It's the easier alternative to `#theme` which doesn't require to implement [`hook_theme()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme/8.8.x) nor putting the template content in a separated file. (If you need to reuse the same inline template in different pages, or the template content is rather complex, using `#theme` is still preferable.)